# MySQL error 1366 (добавление кириллических символов)

Tags: mysql, кодировка, кириллица

В БД имеется таблица, созданная запросом

```
CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `SUBJ_ID` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `SUBJ_NAME` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `HOUR` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEMESTER` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SUBJ_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

При попытке совершить запрос

`insert into SUBJECT (SUBJ_ID, SUBJ_NAME, HOUR, SEMESTER) values (1, 'Биология', 119, 1);`

Возникает ошибка

`Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x91\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBE...' for column 'SUBJ_NAME' at row 1`

Почему возникают проблемы с кодировкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что поле SUBJ_NAME с кодировкой latin1: https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html а вы пытаетесь внести текст 'Биология' в это поле.

Comment: Подскажите, каким запросом можно поменять кодировку поля?

Comment: @Dmitry Лучше создайте новое поле с нужной кодировкой, скопируйте в него данные (с явной конвертацией!), убедитесь, что всё прошло правильно, потом удалите старое поле и переименуйте новое. Так надёжнее, хотя длиннее и геморройнее.

Comment: @Akina а мне уже workbench подсказал правильный запрос)


`ALTER TABLE `university`.`subject` 
CHANGE COLUMN `SUBJ_NAME` `SUBJ_NAME` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;`

Comment: Если в таблице нет данных, то можно попробовать так: ALTER TABLE subject MODIFY SUBJ_NAME varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8; При этом преобразовании пропадут все символы, которые не входят в оба набора символов (utf8 и latin1).

Comment: @Dmitry Я не склонен считать этот запрос правильным. Потому что: 1) в современных условиях более правильно использовать utf8mb4 или хотя бы utf8mb3; 2) Если в процессе конвертации получится неверный результат - отката не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что тип поля нужно изменить на `varbinary(255)`